# Could someone explain how to get the value of a column from a select and assign to another select in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

could someone explain how to pass the value of a column from a select to another select in my case to pass the value cad_products.id_product to the field with the name "parameter"?

follow the code.

```
SELECT
    json_agg ( T ) AS retorno 
FROM
    (
SELECT
    cad_products.*,
    json_agg ( b ) AS properties 
FROM
    cad_products,
    (
SELECT
    cad_properties.id_property,
    cad_properties.description 
FROM
    cad_products_properties
    LEFT JOIN cad_properties  ON cad_products_properties.id_property  = cad_properties.id_property  
WHERE
    cad_products_properties.id_product = **"parameter"**
    ) b 
WHERE
    cad_products.id_agr = 37
GROUP BY
    cad_products.id_product 
    ) T
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what your parameter is and where it's coming from but I would suggest handling that in a join. Also, readability may be somewhat improved with a CTE like the following:

```
WITH data AS
(
SELECT prod.*
     , json_object_agg(prop.id_property, prop.description) AS properties
  FROM cad_products prod
  JOIN cad_products_properties cpp ON (cpp.id_product = prod.id_product) -- Not sure what your parameter is
  LEFT JOIN cad_properties prop ON (cpp.id_property = prop.id_property)
) SELECT JSON_AGG(data) AS retorno;
```

Comment: Thank you @J Spratt! Your contribution
was of great help. I solved my question with your example